# How to make sure function call proper with pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Below code will work when I call like this:

```
char arr[] = "foobar";
reverse(arr);
```

but it won't work when I call like this as it is pointing to read only portion

```
 char*a = "foobar";
 reverse(a);
```

Now my question is that is there any way I can avoid user to call like this?

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
  char * end = str;
  char tmp;
  if (str) 
  { 
     while (*end)
     {      
       ++end;
     }
     --end;
     while (str < end)
     {
        tmp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end-- = tmp;
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char arr[] = "foobar";
```

is array of `char`s, containing these chars: `f`, `o`, `o`, `b`, `a`, `r`, `\0`. While

```
char* a = "foobar";
```

is wrong. `"foobar"` here is a string literal, and this statement must be

```
 const char* a = "foobar"; // note the const
```

You cannot change string literals.

<sub>That is a common mistake - make difference between a pointer and an array.</sub>

---

And no, there's no way to prevent the user to call `reverse` with a string literal. The "user" is responsible for their actions.

If `a` is defined as it must be (using `const`), the compiler will tell "the user" something like `invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’`

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to guarantee that pointer being passed to function is valid. It is impressibility of caller to provide valid data. You can even do something like this

```
  int i = 0xABCD;
  reverse((char*) i);
```

Which doesn't make much sense but there is no way to check for such things in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::string`. Foregoing any corruption, a `std::string` is a continuous block of memory with a known size.

You can even use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Besides with the correct settings, compilers will prevent you from assigning a string literal to a `char*` variable.